# Determine that SocketException was caused by connection loss

Tags: java, sockets

Suppose some code actively works with sockets: creates client and server sockets, writes into SocketOutputStream, reads from SocketInputStream and so on. Of course underlying socket methods may throw `SocketException` and its derivatives.

I differentiate two types of errors. Expected errors - we always should expect network failures and react on them with reconnection or with user-readable error messages. Significant example of expected error is a TCP connection loss. Unexpected errors - something that definitely indicates a bug in our software, such stacktraces should be carefully logged or even should terminate whole application.

I didn't find a reliable way to differentiate SocketException caused by connection loss from any other socket errors. There is no error code in SocketException and no subclasses. All methods from `java.net` package throws just `SocketException` with different error messages:

- `Socket closed` - thrown in most cases.
- `socket closed` - can be thrown from [Windows implementation of `SocketInputStream.socketRead0`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/SocketInputStream.c#l100).
- `Software caused connection abort: .*` - can be thrown from many native methods in Windows.
- `Broken pipe (Read|Write failed)` - can be thrown from [`SocketInputStream.socketRead0`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/SocketInputStream.c#l158) or `SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0` from Unix sockets implementations.
- `socket write error` - in [`SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0` for Windows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/SocketOutputStream.c#l148).
- Probably there are another relevant error messages that I didn't find yet.

Is there any way to determine that specific `SocketException` was caused by a lost TCP connection or the only way is to parse error messages? If so, maybe exists a library that performs that checking? Or maybe I doing something wrong and should always/never ignore any SocketExceptions regardles of their nature?

Comment: 'Socket closed' is a programming error on the local application's part, meaning it had *already* closed the connection from this end. All other `IOExceptions` on a socket except `SocketTimeoutException` are fatal connection errors which indicate that the connection has been lost for one reason or another and the socket must now be closed.

Comment: @user207421 `SocketTimeoutException` is a one of the few exceptions that has clear meaning. It thrown only when there was no events for some socket for soTimeout milliseconds that does not indicate about connection loss.

Comment: Sorry, I missed just one word in your answer and read it incorrectly.

Comment: More like didn't read about five or six at all, surely?